# Get triggered event type in react native

Tags: reactjs, events, react-native, types, native

I've a question about event in React Native, I handle onBlur and onChange event in a TextInput component and I would use a generic event handler for both of this events, but for that I need to get the event type (in order to identify if it is a onBlur or a onChange) in my event Handler, is this possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: `console.log(typeof eventType);` where eventType is the event.

Comment: I tried and I got 'object', and that's logical, because event is an object, what I would like to get is an event type such as 'onBlur' or 'onChange'

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. To identify if it is onBlur or onChange, you would specify SPECIFIC event handlers for each.